# How to do massive bulk inserts against minimongo without dependent queries getting recomputed on each insert

Tags: meteor

In a situation where one needs to insert a very large amount of documents into a minimongo collection, but whose collection already has a few queries depending on it (cursors bound to Template helpers for example), how does one efficiently approach this situation without locking up the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert directly against `_collection.docs`, and then iterate over `_collection.queries` and invalidate via `LocalCollection._recomputeResults()`.

Example:

```
_.each(bulk, function (doc) {
  MyCollection._collection.docs[doc._id] = doc;
});

_.each(MyCollection._collection.queries, function (query) {
  LocalCollection._recomputeResults(query);
});
```