# Loading a Meteor client app with fake fire-and-forget data

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to figure out a good way to create tutorials for using Meteor apps. Visually, I've figured out a good approach, and packed this into a smart package:

> **https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-tutorials**.

However, there is a second piece that turns out to be rather hard to figure out.

In many cases, a tutorial app needs to be loaded with fake data, to demonstrate the interface to the user without requiring it to be populated with real data that may be hard to generate. (For example, see https://www.planapple.com/trip/demo/349/ which is a demo for PlanApple). In Meteor, since the content of an app is basically defined by the contents of some collections, I see two ways to do this:

1. Maintain two sets of collections, one for the tutorial and one for the actual app. Use the first set for the tutorial and the second when the user is actually using the app.
2. Use one set of collections, and fill it with fake data during the tutorial using a subscription and with real data when the user is actually using the app using a different subscription.

The first approach is clearly bad; it means that one cannot write the app without being agnostic to whether it's being used as a tutorial or not and there is a lot of messy `if/else` reactive logic in presenting the app that is unnecessary. Moreover, this will be very hard to maintain if the app has more than a few collections.

The second approach seems to be the more Meteor-esque way to do things. What we basically want is for a server publication to fill all the client collections with some fake data, and then allow the data to be manipulated in whatever way on the client side without the changes propagating to the server; the client basically gets a copy of the server's tutorial data and then makes only local changes to it which are then discarded. This boils down to two things:

- Sending fake data down from the server to client via a custom subscription into the same named collections as the regular app. This is definitely possible as I've written in  **https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880927/586086**
- Ignoring any inserts, updates, and deletes from the client (on the server) after the initial load of data; but allowing them to happen locally. This is also possible if one creates null (unnamed) collections, as in **http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection**.

The problem is that although it's possible to do each of the two steps above separately, I want to do both of them - I want the data to be loaded into the same named collections as the client would have with real data, to avoid the complicated control logic of having two sets of collections, but I also want changes to be local-only but not propagated back over the subscription during the tutorial.

Anyone have ideas about how to do this?

A related question about whether the second part is possible: [How does a Meteor database mutator know if it's being called from a Meteor.method vs. normal code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19527436/586086)

**EDIT:** It seems that what we'd basically want to do in the tutorial is inserting directly against the local Meteor Collection as in {https://stackoverflow.com/a/19523301/586086}. However, is there a way to generally turn on this behavior during the tutorial for all relevant mutators, instead of explicitly having to specify this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing this myself with the **[partitioner](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-partitioner)** package, which allows connected clients to be divided up into different slices each containing different data.

Basically, the idea is to put the user(s) into a new partition when they are in the tutorial, and then put them into another partition when they are using the app for real. Works great with the **[tutorials](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-tutorials)** package as well. This gives up the ability of having changes to be client-local, but storing the tutorial data doesn't have much overhead and turned out to be useful in my case anyway.

An example of an app that does this is https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper.