# How does a Meteor database mutator know if it's being called from a Meteor.method vs. normal code?

Tags: methods, meteor, rpc

If one does something on the client like

```
Foo.insert({blah : 1})
```

where `Foo` is a Meteor collection, this actually triggers a Meteor.method call as documented in the last paragraph of **http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods** that executes code on both the client and the server.

However, let's say I define a method (on client and server) that does the same thing:

```
Meteor.methods({
  bar: function() { 
    Foo.insert({blah : 1}) 
  }
});
```

Now, I trigger this on the client with

```
Meteor.call("bar");
```

`Foo.insert` will now be called both on the client and the server as a result of the method. However, how does the client-side invocation of `insert` know not to call the server again, since it is itself a method?

Moreover, is there a way to call `insert` on the client side **without** automatically triggering the canonical server-side latency-compensation call and resulting synchronization? (For why I'd want to do this, see [Loading a Meteor client app with fake fire-and-forget data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19527210/586086))

Answer (score 1):

The client side one becomes a 'stub'. It has this `isSimulation` property set that makes it appear as if the data is inserted for latency compensation.

I think if a `.method` is run on the client the latency compensation is always enabled and it shouldn't enter in the database. So anything running on a client side method would be a 'fake' type simulation

If you try setting `this.isSimulation` to `false` you'll get some weird error that shows you that the client side insert starts to throw errors with the insert.

I'm not too sure how to run it in a false simulation. I think you'd have to run it off in some other method `var dothis = function() {...}` type method.

To do this 'fake fire' & forget and have client side only data, which is what I presume (please correct if I'm wrong so I change the answer) modify the `_collection` property in your client side method.

e.g if you have

```
mydata = new Meteor.Collection("something");

function something() {
    mydata.insert({..});
}
```

Modify the method to do this instead

```
mydata._collection.insert({..});
```

This will make sure that the data isn't synchronized to the server, yet will have the local collection have this 'fake data'.

Hope this helps!